# Can somebody explain me what is the role of two indices of array instead of single index of array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Why am I getting an error when using `h[0,0]`. Also, what is the the purpose of `h[[0,0]]`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `h[[0, 0]]` gives you 0th postion and 0th position so,

```
print(h[[0, 0]])
# [0, 0]
h[[0, 0]] = [4, 6]
# Equivalent would be 
h[0] = 4
h[6] = 6
```

While for `h[0, 0]` is would raise `IndexError` since `h` is 1-D array here. If it were a 2-D array then it would give you output from 0th row and 0th column value.